# Laravel HTTP Test : How to use sequence in fake call back

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, laravel-8, guzzle

I wonder how to use sequence in HTTP::fake call back.
What I want is to get a sequence of responses when the body of my request contains `ListSupplierRoutes`.
here is my code:

```php
Http::fake(function (Request $request) {
    $body = $request->body();

    $xmlFileName = 'login';
    if (Str::contains($body, 'Login')) {
    $xmlFileName = 'login';
    }

    if (Str::contains($body, 'ListSupplierRoutes')) {
        return Http::sequence()
            ->push($this->loadXMLResponse('list-supplier-routes-ryanair'))
            ->push($this->loadXMLResponse('list-supplier-routes-ezy'));
    }

    // Some other conditions

    return Http::response($this->loadXMLResponse($xmlFileName));
});
```

With this approach I get the below exception:

```
BadMethodCallException : Method Illuminate\Http\Client\ResponseSequence::then does not exist.
    /..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:103
    .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php:730
    .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php:707
    .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php:64
    .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php:37
    .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php:71
    .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php:61
    .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php:75
    .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:331
    .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:168
    .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:187
    .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php:609
    .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:234
    .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php:624
    .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php:528
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `$this->loadXMLResponse()` is returning either a string or an array. Also, the `Http::fake()` requires that you pass an associative array of `url` mapping to `Http::resonse()` type or `Http::sequence()`.

For instance

```php
Http::fake(['http://stackoverflow.com' => Http::sequence()->push('OK', 200)->push('Bad Request', 400)])
```

Comment: You can also create a Http::sequence with an array of Http::responses and each response will be given in order.